# When is it "appropriate" to prove a statement using induction?

Tags: proof-theory

I know the question is broad, but I am just starting to get my hands dirty with mathematical proofs. I understand that in some cases, a "direct" proof may be appropriate if we are simply going step-by-step in a definition-type question.

In other cases, I've found that that proofs by contradiction may be the "easiest" way to go, such as in some linear algebra proofs I've seen.

However, I'm now looking at combinatorial proofs, and notice that something relatively simple such as the proof that $1+2+3+...+n=\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$ uses induction - where if we show that it holds when $n=1$, and we *assume* that it holds when $n=k$, we can reach the desired result.

My question is as follows - is this considered a "weak" argument by any means because of the fact that we are *assuming* some fact to be true? I still have in my mind the old adage "You know what happens when you assume.." Does this same concern generally hold for mathematical proofs?

Comment: It's not considered weaker because something is “assumed”.  You're conflating the colloquial and mathematical usages of the word.  It's a matter of style.  The $1+2+\dots+n = n(n+1)/2$ statement can be proven many ways, and induction is arguably the hardest to follow.

Comment: There is nothing "weak" about "weak induction" in terms of mathematical rigor.  It is particularly useful to prove that something is true for all natural numbers.  However, it is frequently the case that a proof by induction provides less insight than a direct proof.

Comment: Simply put - A proof is a proof, there's no two ways about it. You could write a 100 page proof on something or a simple 1 line proof and both get to the $\textit{exact}$ end result. From my experience induction isn't used very often - but nevertheless very helpful for certain examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three points:

1. As Matthew L. says, there is no such thing as "the" proof of your equation -- it is provable in many ways. Here's a non-inductive one: consider
   $$\ 1\ \ \ +\ \  2 \ \ \ +\ \ \  3\  \quad+ \ldots + n$$
   $$n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \ldots + 1$$
   Add those two vertically and we get
   $$(n +1) + (n +1) + (n +1) + \ldots + (n +1)$$
   So twice the sum of the first $n$ numbers is, trivially, $n(n + 1)$. QED
2. Suppose you want to prove by induction that (C) for all $n$, $Pn$ (for some numerical property $P$). This involves *proving* that (A) $P1$ (usually trivial) and *proving* that (B), for any $j$, if $Pj$ then $P(j + 1)$ 
   (or, if you like, *proving* that if we assume $Pj$ we can deduce $P(j + 1)$). There are no undischarged mere assumptions here!
3. For more on induction and why (A) and (B) give you a proof of (C) -- and for much more on how to start getting your hands dirty with mathematical proofs -- it is difficult to recommend the following too highly, which you should find in any library:

   > Daniel J. Velleman *How to Prove It* (CUP)

Comment: Are you sure that 1. is not a proof by induction? I'm not. `;-)`

Comment: Isn't it a proof of the form "Take any $n$ you like.  Stuff-about-$n$. $n$ was arbitrary. So for all $n$, stuff-about-$n$." Looks like a universal generalization step at the end, rather than induction.

Comment: How do you prove that $1+2+\dots+n=n+\dots+2+1$ without induction?

Comment: Distinguish: "If we are to prove the arithmetical generalization $P$ from the axioms of first-order PA, will induction be needed somewhere along the way?" vs "If we are giving an informal proof of $P$ from assumptions that can, in the classroom context, be taken for granted, do we need to invoke induction?" The answer to the first is almost always "yes", of course. The answer to the second, as in this case, can be "no".